# Graceful shutdown on Archlinux

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, kvm

Bringing this question straight [from here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1891572#p1891572).

I am running archlinux and I have a VM running often on it along with the system. Most of the time actually.

My goal is to produce the following behaviour:

- A shutdown / poweroff / reboot / halt signal is sent to the system
- No action other then trying to shut down the virtual machines gracefully
- If the VMs are shut down gracefully after X seconds, proceeds with shutting down the host system too.
- If not, execute a different command

Just give me a good idea on what to work on, because I don't even know from where to begin. I guess there is a call to the kernel that can be looked at.

Let me know.

---

### My current code

At the moment I am using these scripts to gracefully shutdown my kvm virtual machines, and it works! But only as long as my user launches a *shutdown* or a *reboot* using his shell. Any other case wouldn't work.

These alias:

```
alias sudocheck="/bin/bash /home/damiano/.script/sudocheck"
alias sudo="sudocheck "
```

Are triggering this function:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script checks for what is being passed to sudo.
# If the command passed is poweroff or reboot, it
# launches a custom script instead, that also looks
# fur currently running virtual machines and shuts them.

sudocheck() {
    if [ $1 == "poweroff" ] || [ $1 == "reboot" ]; then
        eval "sudo /home/damiano/.script/graceful $@"
    else
        eval "sudo $@"
    fi
}
sudocheck $@
```

That launches this script if needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
e=0
## if virsh finds VMs running
virsh -c qemu:///system list | awk '{ print $3}' | \
if grep running > /dev/null ; then
    virsh -c qemu:///system list --all | grep running | awk '{print "-c qemu:///system shutdown "$2}' | \
## shuts them dow gracefully
    xargs -L1 virsh
## wait 30 seconds for them to go down
    until (( i >= 30 || e == 1 )) ; do
## check every second for their status
        virsh -c qemu:///system list --all | awk '{ print $3}' | \
        if grep -E '(running|shutdown)' > /dev/null ; then
## keep waiting if still running
            if (( i <= 30 )) ; then
                sleep 1 && let i++ && echo $i
            else
                e=1 && notify-send 'Shutdown has been canceled' 'Please check the status of your virtual machines: seems like even though a stop signal has been sent, some are still running.' --urgency=critical
            fi
        else
## if no machine is running anymore, original power command can be executed
            e=1 && eval $@
        fi
    done
fi
```

---

### Systemd Unit

I also made the following draft, to manage the execution of my VM:

*bootvm@.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=This service manages the execution of the %i virtual machine
Documentation=https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html

[Service]
ExecStartPre=virsh -c qemu:///system
ExecStart=virsh start %i
ExecStop=virsh -c qemu:///system
ExecStop=virsh shutdown %i 
TimeoutStopSec=30
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But how can I tell the system to don't shut down the desktop environment, to stay as it is **UNTIL** the VM has been successfully shut down?
Because if the system can't shut down the vm, I want to do it while still in my DE. I don't want the computer to begin stopping all the services and remain hung until it just forces the shut down.

Comment: This is most probably more appropriate on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did not downvote, but for starters I don't see any actual question in your question. You should make clearer what's going on, why those script are not working as expected etc.

Comment: I didn't think in fact you in particular downvoted the question Marco. Thanks. I just left there the comment for who watched. I'll try to explain further. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If I get what you want to do you're asking for a way to programmatically execute a script before shutdown, right? You should clearly state so, instead of defining what you find elegant or not, which may be unclear. Nonetheless, I still suggest you to move this question to U&L SE.

Comment: Done. Hope that's better

Comment: [I do a systemd service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#With_systemd_service) with `-monitor localhost,<port>` and then send `system_powerdown` to that port. Your use of eval is just wrong. Don't `eval 'something $@'` just `something "$@"`,all uses of your `eval` can be removed from your script. Don't `eval $@`, just `"$@"` - `$@` already is the command, no need to re-parse it.

Comment: `I tell the system to don't shut down the desktop environment, to stay as it is UNTIL` I believe it's `DependsOn=display-manager.target`. But you could edit `display-manager.target` and add `ExecStop=<script to wait for your bootvm@.service>`

Comment: Interesting @KamilCuk!!! Thank you very much! I'll check and let you know